# How can I use older gcc headers?

Tags: linux, gcc, c, headers

I installed `gcc-3.4` to `Debian 7.8` and create symbolic link `/usr/bin/gcc`.
When I typed `gcc --version` I get:

```
gcc (GCC) 3.4.6 (Debian 3.4.6.-9)
```

Then I wrote simple C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

But I get tons of error messages. I think problem is `gcc-3.4` use `gcc-4.7` (default gcc on system) header files. I downloaded `gcc-3.4` from [gcc website](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-3.4.6/gcc-3.4.6.tar.gz) and type :

```
gcc untitled.c -I/home/asd/Desktop/gcc-3.4
```

but not work. How can I use header files of `gcc-3.4` when compiling?

The errors start out like

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from untitled.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/features.h:356:25: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/features.h:388:23: gnu/stubs.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:34,
                 from untitled.c:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/3.4.6/include/stddef.h:213: error: syntax error before "typedef"
In file included from untitled.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:36:25: bits/types.h: No such file or directory
In file included from untitled.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:49: error: syntax error before "typedef"
/usr/include/stdio.h:54: error: syntax error before "__USING_NAMESPACE_STD"
/usr/include/stdio.h: In function `__USING_NAMESPACE_STD':
/usr/include/stdio.h:65: error: storage class specified for parameter `__FILE'
In file included from /usr/include/_G_config.h:20,
                 from /usr/include/libio.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
                 from untitled.c:1:
/usr/include/wchar.h:95: error: storage class specified for parameter `__mbstate_t'
In file included from /usr/include/libio.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
                 from untitled.c:1:
/usr/include/_G_config.h:24: error: syntax error before "__off_t"
/usr/include/_G_config.h:29: error: syntax error before "__off64_t"
/usr/include/_G_config.h:53: error: storage class specified for parameter `_G_int16_t'
/usr/include/_G_config.h:54: error: storage class specified for parameter `_G_int32_t'
/usr/include/_G_config.h:55: error: storage class specified for parameter `_G_uint16_t'
/usr/include/_G_config.h:56: error: storage class specified for parameter `_G_uint32_t'
In file included from /usr/include/libio.h:53,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
                 from untitled.c:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/3.4.6/include/stdarg.h:43: error: storage class specified for parameter `__gnuc_va_list'
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
                 from untitled.c:1:
/usr/include/libio.h:180: error: storage class specified for parameter `_IO_lock_t'
/usr/include/libio.h:300: error: syntax error before "__off_t"
/usr/include/libio.h:310: error: syntax error before "_IO_lock_t"
/usr/include/libio.h:338: error: syntax error before '}' token
/usr/include/libio.h:341: error: storage class specified for parameter `_IO_FILE'
/usr/include/libio.h:346: error: storage class specified for parameter `_IO_2_1_stdin_'
/usr/include/libio.h:347: error: storage class specified for parameter `_IO_2_1_stdout_'
/usr/include/libio.h:348: error: storage class specified for parameter `_IO_2_1_stderr_'
/usr/include/libio.h:364: error: storage class specified for parameter `__ssize_t'
/usr/include/libio.h:364: error: syntax error before "__io_read_fn"
/usr/include/libio.h:372: error: storage class specified for parameter `__ssize_t'
/usr/include/libio.h:372: error: redefinition of parameter '__ssize_t'
/usr/include/libio.h:364: error: previous definition of '__ssize_t' was here
```

The full output of running gcc is available at http://pastebin.com/jFRihqUw

Comment: I kept the question title in my edit just now, but I believe you are looking at this from the wrong end. stdio.h and friends are related not to GCC (the compiler), but to glibc (the standard C library).

Comment: There is no `glibc` package in my system. There are `glibc-doc`, `glibc-doc-reference` and `glibc-source` packages. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

install gcc & g++
For example In linux kali run this in terminal

> apt-get install gcc   g++

for ubuntu use sudo before apt
Then replace path with correct path
In my case **arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/predefs.h>**

because i have arm base device
Follow this for next comming path errors
But by doing this you will get several path issue
So best aproch is

COPY ***asm  , bits  , sys***  & other folder if getting path error
 to **include** folder from **arm-linux-gnueabihf** folder

Answer (score 0):

install gcc & g++
For example In linux kali run this in terminal

> apt-get install gcc   g++

Then replace path with correct path
In my case  correct path is

> arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/predefs.h